# Ember.js: Collapsing/deferring expensive observers or computed properties

Tags: ember.js

In an Ember app, say you have an observer or a property that watches an array, like so:

```
topContributor: (function() {
  // ... loop over articles (hence slow) ...
}).property('articles.@each.author')
```

Updating the `articles` array, through ember-data for instance, repeatedly triggers the property function for a total of `articles.length` times.

Is there a way to collapse the updates into one lazy update when all the changes have finished and the runloop is flushed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to @wagenet and @krisselden for the following pointers:

At the moment, while bindings are deferred (lazy), observers and by extension computed properties trigger immediately. In the future, they [might become deferred as well](http://emberjs.com/blog/2012/10/25/ember-1-0-pre2/).

In the meantime, you can use [Ember.run.once](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_once) as a workaround to schedule a deferred function call, which will be run only once. Computed properties, I suppose, can be easily turned into observers to follow the same pattern. Here is an example:

```
updateTopContributor: function() {
  // ... loop over articles (hence slow) ...
  this.set('topContributor', ...);
},

_updateTopContributorObserver: (function() {
  Ember.run.once(this, 'updateTopContributor');
}).observes('articles.@each.author')
```

Comment: The `updateTopContributor` will be called one time by runloop, but what I don't understand, is how it matches the end of the changes ? I suppose that the `articles` array update takes more than one runloop right ? so `updateTopContributor` will be called multiple times... I probably miss something here, but I'd really understand the flow here. Could you explain me ?

Comment: The end of the runloop happens when the event handling is done. So if an Ajax response comes in for the data store, then it goes update-update-update (triggering the observer repeatedly), and at the very end, before returning to the browser, it will flush the runloop. Conceptually, all of this is similar to deferring a call with `setTimeout(..., 1)`. You might find more info in the [Ember.run reference](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html) and [this blog post](http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2012/04/03/testing-ember-and-the-runloop/).

Comment: Ok, so if I understand, the flow is runLoop1 starts -> ajax response -> schedule updateTopContributor -> end of ajax response -> runLoop1 end -> runLoop1 flushed -> runLoop2 starts -> updateTopContributor triggered -> runLoop2 ends. The first runloop is running while the ajax call has not returned ?