# Ember.js observing changes on an Ember.Object

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a user address form with the standard inputs (name, address, zip, etc). When the user returns to their address I need to watch for changes and disable other options.

I tried:

```
updateAddress: function() {
  console.log('updated')
}.observes(App.Address)
```

`App.Address` is an Ember.Object I end up creating that stores all the user address data. 
The only time this logged out data was when I loaded the page and when I resubmitted the data. But I need it to check it instantly.

Is it possible for me to watch the entire object without doing a good amount of extra work like discussed here: [Ember.js: Observing all object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077439/ember-js-observing-all-object-properties) ?

EDIT: 
Added a JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zadef/3/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: `.observes(..)` should probably take an instance, not a class. Might need a JSBin for additional help...

Comment: @claptimes added a JSBin

Comment: We have something similar in our app, except it's following a plain property on the `App` instance; have you tried `.property('App.Address')`? I'm pretty sure you need to pass a string to [`observes`](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/observers/) as well.

Comment: @PatrickM yeah I've tried both `.property(App.Address)` and `.property('App.Address')` as using `.observes()` with a string passed as the argument.

Comment: Then I think you're out of luck. Just observing an object like that is probably only going to catch changes to the whole reference. If you update a property on the object, the reference is unchanged, and your observer is unchanged.